# Open Specific Worksheet for user

Tags: excel, vba

I have a file with all Team Members with their Individual Data. I have kept the same in One Drive, but unable to control others to see the numbers.

Is it possible for me to assign user-specific access to a worksheet in excel with Employee ID as a Password to open and have an Admin Access to do anything?

Comment: Put a different password on each sheet - only the person for that sheet and you know the password, then each can only access "their" sheet. But don't use employee ID as people can find out each others...

Answer (score 1):

Put a different password on each sheet - only the person for that sheet and you know the password, then each can only access "their" sheet.

I suggest you don't use the employee ID as people can find out each others - why does IT spend so much time chasing us to use sensible passwords?

Also consider the use of vba - on opening it asks for the password and then opens the "correct" sheet - not tried this but interesting. Check out the difference between "hidden" and "Very Hidden" which is available as well.

There are posts on here about using passwords on sheets and hidden / very hidden.